# Disconnection problem using W20 framework

Tags: logout, seedstack

I´m using seedstack 15.11.1 and W20.
When the user click on logout the user is not disconnected from application if the user don´t close the browser.
With a new click in login you are automatically connected to the application without ask user & passoword.
It´s a security risk.
Exist a version of framework that fix this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this feature has been added in W20 version 2.3.0, which is provided since SeedStack 16.4.

[W20 2.3.0 changelog](https://github.com/w20-framework/w20/releases/tag/v2.3.0)

> **[new]** Implement best-effort credentials cleanup for basic
>   authentication (forcing the browser to forget credentials).

The upgrade from 15.11.1 to 16.4 is quite simple but watch out for some [breaking changes](http://seedstack.org/posts/16.4-release-notes/#breaking-changes).